# Can AlexNet outperform ResNet as a feature extractor?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I've been using the pre-trained Deep Learning models as feature extractors on a project involving chest x-ray images to detect TB. I extract the features from the layer just before the Softmax. I could repeatedly find that the performance of AlexNet is way better than ResNet-50. Why is it so?

Comment: What have the AlexNet and ResNet-50 networks you have used been pre-trained on? The names are a little ambiguous - sometimes they refer to the architecture, and sometimes to the same architecture pre-trained on a standard dataset or purpose (ImageNet pre-trains being a common one)

Comment: ResNet-50 is much deeper than AlexNet, so the top layers might be too specialised for your purpose. Have you tried using a mid/high layer from ResNet-50 for comparison?

Comment: These are Imagenet pre-trained Models. I'm a Matlab user and I have the option to only extract the features from the layer before the Softmax, unlike Keras/Tensorflow where I can play with the features from the intermediate layers. So, is the features from the deepest layer of ResNet, highly ImageNet specific which has the least to do with the chest x-ray medical images?

Comment: I don't know, it was just a suggestion. However, intuition based on features becoming progressively more complex and complete in a typical CNN suggests the final pre-softmax layer might not always be the best features to re-use for different tasks, and this could explain the difference in performance in your case.